# Apply function from rgeos package to data sets

Tags: r, distance, spatial-statistics, function, rgeos

I am using gDistance function from rgeos package to calculate the nearest distance from points to a polygon.
Originally I used for loop to calculate the distance for each row in my points data set, however, the speed is extremely slow, especially when I have a large data set. So I tried to use 'apply'.
My codes look like:

```
Invasive_dist <- apply(sp_invasive_pixels, 1, function(x) gDistance(x, sp_tumor))
```

whereas sp_invasive_pixels is my SpatialPoint object, and sp_tumor is the SpatialPolygons object. 
My code does not work, the error message is:

> Error in apply(sp_invasive_pixels, 1, function(x) gDistance(x, sp_tumor)) : 
>     dim(X) must have a positive length

What do I need to change?

## test program:

```
test_poly <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 2))
test_pts <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 2))

test_poly$X1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
test_poly$X2 <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)

test_pts$X1 <- c(4, 5, 6, 7)
test_pts$X2 <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)


sp_pts <- SpatialPoints(test_pts)

sp_poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(test_poly)),1)))
```

Comment: Did you look at the `byid` option? Can you make a simple reproducible example using demo data that we can all run that illustrates your problem?

Comment: @Spacedman yes I can, but how to upload the R data?

Comment: You don't have to upload your data - if its a polygon and some points you should be able to make an illustration using sample data from R packages with maybe test points created from data frames made in a few lines of code - we might only need one polygon and three points to show you how its done.

Comment: @Spacedman Sure, I will edit the question

Comment: I have been using `columbus <- raster::shapefile(system.file("etc/shapes/columbus.shp",package="spdep"))` (needs raster and spdep packages installed) to get a set of polygons, extract the first one `mydata = columbus[1,]` if you only have one in your data.

Comment: @Spacedman test programs were added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your test data, this:

```
> gDistance(sp_poly, sp_pts)
[1] 3.605551
```

returns the distance from the polygon to the nearest point, but if you add `byid=TRUE`:

```
> gDistance(sp_poly, sp_pts, byid=TRUE)
         1
1 3.605551
2 5.000000
3 6.403124
4 7.810250
```

you get a matrix of distances - each row is one of your points. If you have more than one polygon then you get multiple columns.

You can stop reading now if you want...

Let's look at why `apply` failed for you. First can I reproduce that with your test data:

```
> apply(sp_pts, 1, function(x){x})
Error in apply(sp_pts, 1, function(x) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

yes, and I've not needed `gDistance` there so its something more fundamental with the `apply` and its not `gDistance's fault. I suspect`X`here is your points, so what's`dim(sp_pts)`:

```
> dim(sp_pts)
NULL
>
```

`apply` works on data frames, matrices and arrays, but your object has no dimensions!

Perhaps if we make a spatial points *data frame* - which is a data frame with some geometry it will work:

```
> sp_ptsdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp_pts, data.frame(name=LETTERS[1:4]))
> dim(sp_ptsdf)
[1] 4 1
> apply(sp_ptsdf, 1, function(x){x})
Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

no, in this case we get a different error and try another approach. Instead of `apply` we use `sapply` to loop over the indexes of your points (in your test it is 1 to 4) and extract each point inside the function:

```
> sapply(seq_along(sp_pts), function(i){gDistance(sp_pts[i], sp_poly)})
[1] 3.605551 5.000000 6.403124 7.810250
```

Finally something that works! But note this is the same answer as using `byid=TRUE` but it will be much slower. I only add this to explain where your error is coming from and to show a general technique which might be useful if you want to apply some other function by rows of a spatial points object.

Comment: This is a really detailed explanation! thank you so much

Comment: Also wondering whether use 'byid = TRUE ' is the fastest way, since the point set includes over 500k points, so that the speed is really important.

Comment: Try it. Also, try using the `sf` package for your point and polygon objects, and `st_distance`.